# How would I go about mass converting CSS variables back to their original values?

Tags: css, css-variables

Essentially, let's say I have the following code:

```css
html {
  --pink: #ffe4f1;
  --yellow: #fff7d1;
  --green: #e4f9e0;
  --purple: #f2e6ff;
  --blue: #e2f1ff;
  --gray: #f3f2f1;
  --charcoal: #696969;
}

.pink { color: var(--pink); }
.yellow { color: var(--yellow); }
.green { color: var(--green); }
.purple { color: var(--purple); }
.blue { color: var(--blue); }
.gray { color: var(--gray); }
.charcoal { color: var(--charcoal); }
```

But what I really want is:

```css
.pink { color: #ffe4f1; }
.yellow { color: #fff7d1; }
.green { color: #e4f9e0; }
.purple { color: #f2e6ff; }
.blue { color: #e2f1ff; }
.gray { color: #f3f2f1; }
.charcoal { color: #696969; }
```

---

So, how would I go about changing all variables (which there would be more than one occurrence of), without doing it by hand? I know it would basically be a CSS downgrading compiler of sorts, but is there anything like that out there yet? And if not, is there at least a project in the works for it?

Another thing to mention is, there is going to be multiple instances of the variables in the css script, and other situations such as duplicate variables being set (one in :root, and another in a selector to override in that scope).

One of the reasons for wanting to do this is to have legacy CSS support for older browsers/webviews.

Comment: It probably took you longer to write this question than to just manually change them :D

Comment: Also, take a look at this: https://github.com/MadLittleMods/postcss-css-variables

Comment: @JeremyHarris ... the file I need to convert is much larger, more variables, multiples instances of the variables everywhere, and with more complicated names... so it would take forever replacing every value by hand, even with Notepad++ find and replace feature.

Comment: That github page is actually really nice. I'll probably code a bit of something up for my purpose so I can get my files converted. Thanks @JeremyHarris

Comment: the real question is: why you want to do this?

Comment: Sure no problem. If you end up making something, maybe drop a link on the comments here in case somebody else is looking for this in the future.

Comment: I am little bit confuse ,both scenarios gives the same result why would you want that

Comment: @TemaniAfif To support older browser versions, such as older WebView versions on android

Comment: @Awais look above

Comment: Well then rather then changing just override that at the end of style-sheet, it took less time and easy to track down if anything goes wrong

Answer (score 0):

I would write a shell script to modify the CSS files:

```
#!/bin/bash

css_file=style.css

# I will suppose that each variable definition is alone on one line

for color_code_pair in $(grep '^ *--[a-zA-Z]*:' $css_file |
  sed -e 's/^ *--//' -e 's/; *$//' -e 's/: *//') ;
do
  color=${color_code_pair%#*}       # remove '#' and everything after
  code=${color_code_pair#*#}        # remove '#' and everything before

  # I will suppose the css lines have a similar structure

  # sed command below changes the color name into the hexadecimal code 
  sed -i "s/var(--$color)/#$code/" $css_file

  # sed command below deletes the variable definition 
  sed -i "/^ *--$color:/d" $css_file

done
```

Comment: That is very good too, but cavets like these* are abundant with what I'm working with.
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
* https://github.com/MadLittleMods/postcss-css-variables#caveats